# Simple ways to determine $\rm LiNbO_3$ wafer orientation

Tags: experimental-physics, crystals, piezoelectric

Let's say I am to receive a bunch of lithium niobate wafers, Y-127 cut.

There's a wafer flat which indicates the direction of the X-axis. However the wafer still has a top and bottom. Since we're working with a rotated cut, the wafer surface is not a crystallographic mirror plane.

How do I easily determine which orientation the wafer has? I have access to some basic optic and electrical components.

Comment: The easiest would be a diffractometer.

Comment: Had a brainwave: I'm going to try simply lightly compressing it between two conductive surfaces and measuring the piezo voltage polarity with an oscilloscope or even a multimeter. Will add an answer if it works.